# cut command - How to find the end of line with N bytes

Tags: command-line, cut-command

I want to cut a line from the 13<sup>th</sup> byte until the end of the line, but I don't know how many bytes there are in the line.

How can I find the end of the line?

I tried to do:

```
cut -b 13-CRFL $textfile
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man cut`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/cut.1.html) (I have bolded the relevant option):

```
Use one, and only one of -b, -c or -f.  Each LIST is made up of one range, or many ranges  sepa‐
rated  by  commas.   Selected input is written in the same order that it is read, and is written
exactly once.  Each range is one of:

N      N'th byte, character or field, counted from 1

N-     from N'th byte, character or field, to end of line

N-M    from N'th to M'th (included) byte, character or field

-M     from first to M'th (included) byte, character or field
```

So you just have to use:

```
cut -b 13- $textfile
```